# Cannot install php7-mongodb in alpine linux

Tags: mongodb, docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I am trying to install php7-mongodb with my dockerfile. The same worked until yesterday but today dockerbuild is throwing the following error

```
Step 4/12 : RUN apk add php7-mongodb
 ---> Running in b6713ea15c9d
  php7-mongodb (missing):
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
    required by: world[php7-mongodb]
The command '/bin/sh -c apk add php7-mongodb' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I tried with apk update and apk upgrade in the dockerfile but still not working. any idea what the issue is?

I am using alpine edge as base version.

We can recreate the issue by using the following dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:edge
RUN echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing" >> /etc/apk/repositories
RUN apk update && apk upgrade
RUN apk add  php7-mongodb
```

Answer (score 5):

tldr: The package renamed to `php7-pecl-mongodb` in 3.9 and no longer exists in later releases

The package was renamed to `php7-pecl-mongodb` with this commit: https://git.alpinelinux.org/aports/commit/?id=b3d534d73c690baf458d9cda5dca5ee52ca9cafc

But the package was removed shortly after that due to a nonfree licence change by the package: https://git.alpinelinux.org/aports/commit/community/php7-pecl-mongodb/APKBUILD?id=8a901de31fa055ed591d487e12f8bb9ffcc0df21

Answer (score 2):

According to https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=php7-mongodb&branch=edge there is no such package in alpine edge version.

The latest alpine version that has the `php7-mongodb` package in its repos seems to be 3.8: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=php7-mongodb&branch=v3.8

I can't tell you what's the reason that this package is not contained in 3.9 and edge. But if this is an option for you use `alpine:3.8` as the base image instead of `alpine:edge`

Answer (score 2):

Using Alpine 3.8 will fix the issue for you. Change

```
FROM alpine:edge
```

To

```
FROM alpine:3.8
```

You will also need to change the repository URL so it's point at v3.8. I've been using main so the second line would look like below for me.

```
RUN echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories
```

I don't think `/testing` exists for older releases so you'll need to experiment to find out what works for you. Or perhaps someone else can clarify this for us.

It means you're not using the latest Alpine but you will be able to build the container.